# Related to change in sign from " = " to "<" inside probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand how the "$=$" sign gets changed to "$<$" sign inside probability in the equation given in one of the research paper which is written below:

$$P_1 = \text{Pr}(\beta = 0) \tag{1}$$

where $\text{Pr}$ denotes the probability. $\beta$ has the expression given by
$\beta =1-\frac{\phi}{P_s|h|^2}$, where $\phi,P_s$ are constants and $h$ is a random variable.
So substituting this expression of beta in Eq. $(1)$.

$$P_1 = \text{Pr}\!\left(1-\frac{\phi}{P_s|h|^2} = 0\right) \tag{2}$$

$$P_1 = \text{Pr}\!\left(|h|^2 < \frac{\phi}{P_s}\right) \tag{3}$$

My query is how "$=$" sign in  Eq. $(2)$ got changed to "$<$" sign in Eq. $(3)$.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose $h$ must be a *discrete* random variable, right? I'd think it's related to that -- like how for a geometric variable $X$, $\mathbb P(X = 0) = \mathbb P(X < 1)$. Just guessing, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply sir....$|h|^2$ is exponential random variable....

Comment: I had checked the Wikipedia and found that exponential distribution is continuous analogue of the geometric distribution.  Did you mean some thing like this....

Comment: No, that's fundamentally different. Exponential variables are continuous, and the probability of an exponential variable taking *any* particular value is equal to 0 (as with any continuous random variable). So I'm afraid that you must be mistaken about some part of this, because otherwise the probability in (2) would necessarily be zero, and the probability in (3) would necessarily be positive.

Comment: I had checked once again.....$|h|^2$ is exponential random variable only...

Comment: I'm sorry, because I'm not sure what to say here, other than that the probability of $|h|^2$ assuming any constant value is always 0. Maybe one of your constants isn't actually a constant, but a random variable that is somehow dependent on $h$? Or maybe there's a translation error somewhere and by "exponential" you mean something else (like geometric, for instance)?

Comment: Yes... $P_s$ is not the constant its an random variable...